# unique cube arrangments

Tags: combinatorics, 3d, geometry

i have received this math riddle which i cannot solve,

the riddle:

given a set of cubes, a unique shape is any shape that was created joining cubes sides together and does not match any previously created shapes.

for example

- if we have a set of 2 cubes there is only 1 unique shape (2 cubes connected)
- given a set of 3 cubes there is only 2 unique shapes (L shape and straight line)
- with 4 cubes there are 8 unique shapes,

[you must use all cubes in shape]

what is the number of unique shapes for an N cube set ?

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A000162

Comment: @BarryCipra thanks, although i cant really understand how to read the formula noted in page.

Comment: Mike, if you're referring to the three formulas that appear beneath the section labeled "links," they relate your sequence to others.  There doesn't appear to be any simple known formula for computing the number of unique shapes as a function of $N$.